# Javascript for loop not looping

Tags: javascript

I have some code that I'm working on for my work. We're trying to loop through all the links  on our page and automatically add an onclick event. However, the loop doesn't appear to be  "looping" at all. Could somebody please help?

```
var ourdomainname = "ourdomain.com";


function linkallthelinks(domain) {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var link = links[i];
        var href = link.getAttribute("href");

        if (href.indexOf(read_today) != -1) {
            link.setAttribute('onclick', 'alert("Okay")');
        }
    }
}
//function call
linkallthelinks(ourdomainname);​
```

Comment: `link.setAttribute('onclick', 'alert("Okay")');` <<< this is **NOT** how you attach events.

Comment: Is it entering the function? do you have an error message? Have you checked the length of the list?

Comment: Is `read_today` a variable?  Should it be `'read_today'`?

Comment: read_today is undefined, apparently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing quotes here:

```
if(href.indexOf(read_today) != -1)
```

Should be:

```
if(href.indexOf('read_today') != -1)
```

Overall, this is what you should have:

```
var ourdomainname = "ourdomain.com";

function linkallthelinks(domain) {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        var link = links[i];
        var href = link.getAttribute("href");

        if (href.indexOf('read_today') != -1) {
            link.setAttribute('onclick', 'alert("Okay")');
        }
    }
}
//function call
linkallthelinks(ourdomainname);​
```

Comment: Don't put quotes around the `onclick` function.

Comment: This: `link.setAttribute('onclick', function(){ alert("Okay") });` is incorrect. OP was doing it correctly. The `'alert("Okay");'` gets automatically wrapped in a function.

Comment: @Rocket: It's setting an *attribute*, not a property, so either way it's getting the `.toString()` treatment.

Comment: Oh, my bad on the quotes around "read_today". Thanks for the catch! However, loop still does not appear to be looping because no events are being attached to the links...

Comment: @user1250254: Have you tested the `.length` of the `a` elements returned? `alert(links.length);`? Are you running your script before the elements have been loaded into the page?

Comment: Thanks for your help everybody! @amnotiam You were right! I just moved my script from the header to the footer and everything worked. Thanks everybody!

Comment: @harrier: Since you are new here, plz check out how to accept an answer that helped you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if(link.href.indexOf("read_today") != -1)
```